# Add computer name to Windows 11 Taskbar

Tags: windows, taskbar, desktop

I would really like to have my Computer Name displayed in the windows taskbar or overlaid onto it.  I used to do this in Windows 10 by adding a toolbar to the taskbar but this seems to have been removed in Win11.  I have changed the taskbar accented colour so I can differentiate but this means you need to know what colour signifies which machine so a basic label would be much more preferable.

Google seems to be referring more to the removal of application labels and not this issue.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Right context off the taskbar is gone in Windows 11. You may need to make your own Icon for a do-nothing app to put on the taskbar. Otherwise the function you want no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right context off the taskbar is gone in Windows 11. There is no sign of it coming back, not even in Windows 11 Insider.

You might try this article to pin an icon to the taskbar in Windows 11 and this might possibly help you.

Otherwise the function you want no longer exists.

[Pin to taskbar](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-taskbar-pin-almost-anything/)

> How to Pin an Open App to the Windows 11 Taskbar By default, the
> Windows 11 taskbar comes with the Start menu, Task View, Widgets,
> Chat, File Explorer, Microsoft Edge, and the Microsoft Store pinned on
> it. However, you can add more apps to it, including the ones you
> currently have open right now.
>
> Whenever you open an app, its icon pops up on the taskbar. From here,
> you can pin the app to the taskbar by doing the following:
>
> Right-click or press and hold on to the app's icon on the taskbar.
> Click/tap on Pin to taskbar.

Comment: Thanks John - shame its been removed but hey i guess thats progress?

Answer (score 1):

Same here, my workaround needs to hover over.
Created a shortcut to timeout.exe, modified icon to "Person", caption to user@machine and pinned it to the taskbar.